Where to change roaming agressiveness if it's not in the device setting?

I've been trying to connect to a specific access point under one public ssid via wifiinfoview and NetSetMan but every time I try to connect, it snaps back to the one with better signal. I'm assuming this is because of roaming agressiveness but I can't find how to disable it.

Specifically trying to connect to 34-8A-12-0B-32-31 but every time I do it goes back to 34-8A-12-0A-65-71. I've confirmed that access point is avalible as I have two other devices connected to it.

If the driver doesn't support that function, you won't find it in that dialog. I would suggest that a better idea is to tell your computer not to automatically connect to the stronger network, or, delete it from your list of known networks.

We need to know more about the access point. Additionally, what driver are you using, it appears this device’s driver is erroneously very aggressive with regards to roaming. We cannot help without additional information

Driver version is RTK_6001.15.123.306_MTK_23.32.2.558 as listed from lenovo

-52dBm is 20x the power of -65dBm. Even the most timid roaming algorithm is going to make that jump immediately. It's unquestionably the right thing to do.
